# Redux Reducer nested data

Tags: redux, reducers

I have been stuck on this concept for a while now. I need to update the 'votes' in an object such as this. What am I doing wrong?

```
    export default function restaurantReducer(state = initialState.restaurants, action) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case 'UPDATE_RESTAURANT':
            return [
                ...state,
                {
                    ...state[action.key],
                    ['votes']: action.userName
                }
            ];
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

The data I have is

```
{
    restaurants: {
        ID: {
            name : 'name',
            votes : {
                voterID: 'voters name',
                voterID: 'voters name',

            }   
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to be able to add ID's and names to the votes...

initial-state.js is:

```
const initialState = {
  auth: {
    status: 'ANONYMOUS',
    email: null,
    displayName: null,
    photoURL: null,
    uid: null
  },
  messages: {
  },
  users: {
  },
  restaurants: {
  },
};

export default initialState;
```

Comment: Can you post what `initialState.restaurants` is?

Comment: @sma I just updated the question for you. Thanks for your help

Comment: Also, what is being published by your action?  i.e. what is the reducer receiving in the UPDATE_RESTAURANT case?